# How to call a function with argc & argv?

Tags: c++, c, qt

I'm currently trying to create a GUI for an existing command line program using QT, as a learning exercise.

The original code was written in c, and I have included the c wrapper for the c++ bit. I have taken the original

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

and turned it into a normal function (changed the name).

I have several qt checkboxes made to act as the input, (e.g. -v activated verbose in the cmdline, so now I have a verbose checkbox that makes char verbose = to "v")

There are also several other arguments that take numbers, eg -t 4 for 4 threads.

The options in the original program are implemented like so:

```
while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "vqnrik1eE:P:NTX:F:t:h?f:o:s:")) != -1) {
    switch (opt) {
case 'v':
        verbose = 2;
        break;
```

etc

How can I call all these different options as a standard function? I can write the whole argument to one large string and feed that in if possible, but how would I go about doing this?

Thanks,

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in/129632#129632

Comment: What is the command line program doing? Does it always run quickly (ie less than a tenth of a second)? If it could run in more than a few seconds, your approach is wrong (you can't afford freezing the GUI for several seconds)

Answer (score 4):

You should probably move away from the arguments and set the control variables directly:

```
if(verboseCheckBox->checked()){
    verbose=2;
}
//etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call with an array of strings like so:

```
char* argv[4] = {executing_path, "-t 4","v","random_argument"};
const int argc = sizeof(argv)/sizeof(char*);
main(argc, argv);
```

Note that the first parameter is usually a full path to the executable which you receive in the main function. If possible, I would keep the same behavior; sometimes, the code parsing arguments is doing it in range `1... n-1` therefore skipping the first value in the array.

Now that you know how to do it, I would also advise against it. Since you are already in the source code you should probably use direct method calls in order to set the options as ratchet freak explained in his answer.